# Mapping of 1:N with total participation

Tags: database, one-to-many

I am having a difficulty in finding the mapping of 1:N relationship with total participation on the 1 side. Do I have to just put the primary key of N side entity in the 1 side relation?

Comment: Can you give example to be more clear?

Comment: I am doing relational mapping of ER model.

Comment: For example i have 2 entities,
Student(Sid,Name,Age) Sid is key
Professor(Pid,Name,Age) Pid is key

And i have 1: N as Student:Professor with total participation on Student

Answer (score 0):

In a one-to-many relationship, despite which side has total participation, foreign key is included in the many side relation.

Example:- One E1 has many E2. One E2 has one E1. And E1 participates totally. In this case we take the primary key of E1 and put it in the E2 relation as a foreign key.